# UPS phase rotation issue

Tags: three-phase

I have a 208 V 3~ 10 kW UPS backing up an environmental chamber. When energized the UPS faulted a reverse rotation alarm. I flipped the disconnect and changed two legs then re-energized only to get another reverse polarity fault. Could a heavy load on one phase cause it to do that?

This power is on a 480 V step down 30 kVA transformer with literally no other load. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw a schematic of what you have and how it's connected. If you click on edit and the schematic symbol, a schematic editor will open and you can insert your schematic into your question.

Comment: What is the connection of the transformer secondary?  If it is delta, or ungrounded wye, the UPS may be reacting to a common-mode voltage.

Comment: Try reversing any two of the three power leads from the UPS, that should reverse it so it is now in rotational sync with the mains.

Comment: Any ideas? Yes, but that can be anything. How is the error message generated? What measurement does the system do? Are there any instructions from the manufacturer of the UPS?